# jQuery Mobile passing parameters in URL

Tags: jquery, url, mobile, parameters, anchor

I have a landing site which takes an id parameter which is then used to load the appropriate page. I would like to send the same id to the next page. It looks like this.

```
var pageID= "#gcn-lg-biz-detail-page?pid=" + mem.id;
$.mobile.changePage( pageID, { transition: "flip"} );
```

This is currently working. The problem is that the original id from the landing page is still in the URL of the next page. It looks like this.

Landing Page

```
www.example.com/go/?id=1034
```

Following Page

```
www.example.com/go/?id=1034#gcn-lg-biz-detail-page?pid=1034
```

As you can see there is an extra id from the initial page in the url. I realize that I probably don't need to send the id a second because its already in there from the original URL but second page will not always follow the landing page, It may be loaded after a use clicks on a list item which I would then need to pass the id.

I need to know how to clean the URL before the `$.mobile.changePage()` so that the URL is clean with just the hash and parameters following it. Basically I just want to to look like this.

```
www.example.com/go/#gcn-lg-biz-detail-page?pid=1034
```

Comment: I created a [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) that might help you if you're still having issues with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can reconstruct your url this way:

```
var cleanUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + window.location.hash
```

I'm not totally sure if this answers your question.